# Uncaught ReferenceError: header is not defined ..This error is popping up .. I'm trying to add div element into the html document

Tags: javascript

```
const message = document.createElement('div');
message.classList.add('cookie-message');

message.innerHTML =
  'We use cookied for improved functionality and analytics. <button class="btn btn--close-cookie">Got it!</button>';

// header.prepend(message);
header.append(message);
```

I want to add the div element to document ..but it's not appending or prepending.

Comment: So what is `header`? Where does it come from?

Comment: The error says it all. `header is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

header is not defined, you need to query it from your website
for example:

```
let header = document.querySelector('header')
```

or if your element has id = header

```
let header = document.getElementById('#header')
```

or if header is class of element

```
let header = document.querySelector('.header')
```

Comment: So how will that help ? `header` will still be not defined Where is `header = ...` ???

Comment: yeah, sorry, should have added the header = before that